# (Menu) Command that defines alias in bash script, and invokes when typing its name in console

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, menu

I am trying to make menu for my script, I have separated all those functions, But only way user can open them from command line is like this:

`./Name.sh`

I just want them to make a shortcut of it, So they can just type this in.

`Name`

I have tried to add alias in the shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 Alias name='source ./Name.sh'
```

But there's problem, Whenever i type in "name" (without quotation marks) in console nothing happens.

I am beginner at Bash, So is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command name is `alias`, not `Alias`. Just source your script to get the alias definition in **this** shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias name='source ./name.sh'
```

If this script is called script.sh, execute `. ./script.sh` to get the alias defined, or just add the alias to `~/.bashrc`.

Test that your alias is correctly defined with `alias name`

```
$ alias name
alias name='source ./name.sh'
```

Comment: Thanks, i spent hours to find this out, but now i got another problem, Scripts also had some other commands in, It could CD to file's $PATH, so it would locate all other files to open them, But here's error that i just got after executing script:   -bash: cd: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory

Comment: EDIT: I fixed that problem by just adding "CD $PATH" at start thanks so much for helping again :)

Comment: You could not CD to the value of a normal PATH variable, it has **several** paths separated by colon (:). You could place the script in a known location `~/` for example, and source it as this: `~/script.sh`. It is however a common practice to place user scripts inside `~/bin`, which `.bashrc` normally includes in the `$PATH` by default. If so, calling the script as `. script.sh` will source it directly from `~/bin/script`.

Comment: Oh yeah i'm gonna try doing that, Thanks a lot.